# change gsettings without running X and Unity

Tags: xorg, gsettings

I am trying to change some gconf settings in Ubuntu 12.10. I would like to change the lightdm greeter background.

I have discovered that while logged in to unity as a user while running X server, I am able to do this with:

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background "'/usr/share/backgrounds/micros-background.png'"
```

The problem is that this requires me to login as a user under X. So that entire window manager needs to be running. But I want to use chroot to change these settings without any X server running. I just want to mount the partitions and change gsettings without having the full window manager running.

Is there a way to directly change gsettings without being logged into X and Unity?

Or alternatively... is there a way to bring up the X server and Unity in the background so that I can make the changes without having a full windowed display come up on my monitor?

Answer (score 17):

It's [possible](http://php.mandelson.org/wp2/?p=565) to run `gsettings` without X11 using `dbus-launch --exit-with-session`:

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background "'/usr/share/backgrounds/micros-background.png'"
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I used this to set settings for another user not logged in like this `sudo -u "username" dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'`

Comment: If you prepend the line 5cdhn suggests with sudo, you can edit root's dconf (when using dconf-editor and gsettings with sudo/gksu throw this error). Another way to do this is with 'sudo/gksu dbus-launch gsetttnigs/dconf-editor' as Paco Porras suggests.

Comment: This does not appear to work when you have a session currently running. For example, I want to change keyboard layout when I plug/unplug the keyboard. Running gsettings inside a udev script, even using dbus-launch, does not apply the settings for the currently running session.

Comment: “No protocol specified” on attempt to test this.

Answer (score -1):

Some people says that you must precede the "gsettings" command by the "dbus-launch" word, but I haven't tried it.