# Can't execute nmcli in an upstart job

Tags: network-manager, upstart

The file below is the default network-manager.conf upstart job.

```
$ cat /etc/init/network-manager.conf
# network-manager - network connection manager
#
# The Network Manager daemon manages the system's network connections,
# automatically switching between the best available.

description "network connection manager"

start on (local-filesystems
      and started dbus
      and static-network-up)
stop on stopping dbus

expect fork
respawn

script
    # set $LANG so that messages appearing on the GUI will be translated. See LP: 875017
    if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
        . /etc/default/locale
        export LANG LANGUAGE LC_MESSAGES LC_ALL
    fi

    exec NetworkManager
end script
```

I want to execute `sudo nmcli nm enable false` **after** network-manager is started, but
I can't get it to work in an upstart job. I have tried two different ways.

### First attempt

```
$ sudo vi /etc/init/network-manager.override
# network-manager - network connection manager
#
# The Network Manager daemon manages the system's network connections,
# automatically switching between the best available.

description "network connection manager"

start on (local-filesystems
      and started dbus
      and static-network-up)
stop on stopping dbus

expect fork
respawn

script
    # set $LANG so that messages appearing on the GUI will be translated. See LP: 875017
    if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
        . /etc/default/locale
        export LANG LANGUAGE LC_MESSAGES LC_ALL
    fi

    exec NetworkManager
    exec /usr/bin/nmcli nm enable false <-- added this

end script
```

**FAILS**

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/upstart/network-manager.log
** (process:3453): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

** (process:3453): WARNING **: Error enabling/disabling networking: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

### Second attempt

```
$ sudo vi /etc/init/network-manager-disable.conf
#start on started network-manager <-- tested as well but doesn't work
start on starting network-manager

task

exec /usr/bin/nmcli nm enable false
```

**FAILS**

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/upstart/network-manager-disable.conf
** (process:2423): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

** (process:2423): WARNING **: Error enabling/disabling networking: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

`sudo nmcli nm enable false` works fine on the command line, but not in upstart.
Btw I **don't** want to remove the network-manager, e.g. `echo "manual" > /etc/init/network-manager.override`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not need sudo in the upstart job. This is probably not what is causing your issue, but the usage is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks yeah I removed it earlier but didn't update it here. Will do now.

Comment: Try `exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session nmcli ...`, like in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276509/change-gsettings-without-running-x-and-unity).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the second method, but make sure to use the `started network-manager` event and then add a line with `pre-start exec sleep 2`.