# How to disable network with crontab on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, cron

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and try to disable network on scheduled time everyday. For example disable it at 5pm everyday.

The first thing I tried is `crontab` as below:

```
0 17 * * * nmcli nm enable false
```

and

```
0 17 * * * nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0
```

Both `nmcli` commands work fine at shell, but can't see it working in `crontab`.

Can anyone help me to find out why it doesn't work in `crontab`?

Or is there any other solution to automatically turn off network on schedule?

Comment: `nmcli` uses DBus, so you could try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/276509/change-gsettings-without-running-x-and-unity, other way is more brutal: `sudo ip link set down dev eth0`.

Comment: How about stopping the nm service directly instead i.e. `/usr/sbin/service network-manager stop`?

Comment: Thank @muru for your quick response. My limited knowledge make it hard for me to understand the DBus things. But the brutal way works for me.

Comment: I'll post an answer, then.

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, When I try your command, I got an error message "stop: Unknow job: network" when run as user and "stop: Job failed while stopping" as root.

Comment: Yes you must run it as root (or with sudo). I was assuming you would use root's crontab. Did you miss the hyphen? make sure you typed `network-manager` not `network manager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nmcli` uses DBus, so you could try using `dbus-launch` as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276509/change-gsettings-without-running-x-and-unity). It would look like:

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0
```

Apparently, this only works for the root user.

The other way is more direct:

```
sudo ip link set down dev eth0
```

Used in root's crontab, or in `/etc/crontab`, the `sudo` wouldn't be required.

Comment: I tried the `dbus-launch` command, it only works for `root` not for users. maybe you can add that in your answer to make it more clear. Sorry, low reputation and can't vote up for your answer.

Comment: Ah! an answer instead of a comment (and a good one, so upvoted!)  ;-)